# My WordPress site's breadcrumbs are appearing twice in Google SERP

Tags: google-search, wordpress, search-results, breadcrumbs

My site is built with WordPress using the Genesis framework.

Currently in Google search results, my site's breadcrumbs are being displayed twice - see the following screenshot:

[image: Breadcrumbs appearing twice]

How might I correct this?

Comment: Yes, it is showing that, but why do you care?  The link works perfectly.

Comment: It looks odd. Yoast seo plugin is also used. Is it due to that.

Comment: Check the html source code of the page. How does it look?

Comment: Sometimes a simple step fixes frustrations especially a minor issue of yours that 90+% of the people don't care about. Most of the time I don't care about the green text in google's search results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely due to the fact that the breadcrumb meta data is included on the page twice. [image]

As you can see in the source code from your website, the breadcrumb RDFa metadata is included twice, at two different points. One before the main content, and again afterwards.

Remove one instance (probably the later one should be removed) and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for solution. I am currently using Yoast seo plugin. How to remove the double breadcrumb.

Comment: Most likely the breadcrumbs are being called at two different points in your theme files, one before the content body and again afterwards. I'd start by looking there.